# DVI inverse search settings in WinEdt

Tags: winedt, forward-inverse-search, dvi

I am using WinEdt for latex codes. After running the code, I check the result in a dvi file. Somebody told me that we can directly jump from dvi file to latex code window by double clicking on some line in dvi file. Can anybody help me how to make that setting. Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1 - WinEdt version? 2 - Are you using MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: version is 5.5.2007.921

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, to enable forward/inverse search between WinEdt and your DVI previewer, you must be sure that the compiler is generating source specials.

In WinEdt, take a look at the status bar and see if there is a panel containing `--src`. If not, click on that panel (see the image below) to enable source specials.

[image]

Regarding the DVI previewer, latest versions of dviout (DVI previewer bundled with TeX Live) automatically recognise WinEdt when you double-click on the dvi output (if dviout was launched by WinEdt).

If, instead, you are using Yap (DVI previewer bundled with MiKTeX) you might need to configure it to interact with WinEdt.

In Yap, go to "View" -> "Options" -> "Inverse DVI Search" panel and you should see that WinEdt is already auto-detected. Simply click on "WinEdt (auto-detected)" and then "OK".

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. :) And yes, I am using Yap.